# How many items for a reliable Fleiss kappa?

Tags: agreement-statistics

Suppose that I have N items that were rated by a first group of annotators on a scale from 1 to 5 (each item was rated only once). I want to compute an inter-annotator agreement score using Fleiss kappa, so I take a subset of the N items and ask different annotators to rate the items again. So, in the end, each item in the subset will be rated by 2 different annotators.

My question is: what subset size should I pick in this situation? Is there any method to find what size is "enough" to guarantee that the kappa will be reliable? If not, is it possible to check, after computing the kappa, whether the subset was large enough?

Comment: "I have N items that were rated by a first group of annotators on a scale from 1 to 5." doesn't this step already give you items that have been rated by 2 different annotators (or even more)? Or should I interpret the first step as each item being only rated by a single annotator?

Comment: Sorry: each item is rated by only one annotator.

Comment: And in the subset each item is only rated once as well? Then you can approach this as a binomial distribution.

Comment: But... the variance/reliability will depend on the actual degree of agreement and also on the ratings. For instance, if all annotators are highly positive and only use ratings 4 and 5, then it is much more likely to get agreement compared to the situation of highly differentiated annotators that use the full scale from 1 to 5. Therefore... I don't think that it is possible to decide on the subset size beforehand (unless you have some prior ideas about the distributions), and you can only assess it afterwards.

Comment: But the rates given to the N items should give me an estimation of this distribution, right?